# Is there a way to track when a method of some metadata has been called?

Tags: c#, metadata, xpo

I'm using a *NuGet* Package called **DevExpress.Xpo** and its classes are uneditable because they're locked as "metadata". The package contains a class called *DataStorePool*, and, during runtime, I need to somehow be able to log whenever one of its methods is called. For example, when the *AcquireChangeProvider* method is called, I want to log that it's been called (with a simple *Console.WriteLine*), but I can't directly add any code to the method itself because it's uneditable. I think I need some way to "listen" to when the method is called, but how do I achieve this?

Comment: At runtime or while debugging?

Comment: I need to be able to check at runtime

Comment: Wrap the immutable class in your own code that adds logging functionality

Comment: I was thinking along that line too, but I'm unaware how to wrap it in my own class. Do you have a small bit of example code?

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap any package with your own class.

Here is a simplified example:

**Your class**

```
public class DictionaryWrapper<TKey, TValue> : Dictionary<TKey, TValue>
{
    public DictionaryWrapper() : base() {
        Console.WriteLine("A New Dictionary was created");
    }

    public new void Add(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"A value is being added to a dictionary.{Environment.NewLine}\tKey: {key}{Environment.NewLine}\tValue:{value}");

        base.Add(key, value);

        Console.WriteLine($"A new dictionary value was added.{Environment.NewLine}\tKey: {key}{Environment.NewLine}\tValue:{value}");
    }
}
```

Execute code that uses your new class and method.

```
var dictionary = new DictionaryWrapper<string, int>();

dictionary.Add("SomeValue", 1);

Console.WriteLine(dictionary.First().Key);
Console.WriteLine(dictionary.First().Value);
```

Comment: This answer uses a Dictionary instead of the DataStorePool, and the "new" implementation doesn't seem to work with DataStorePool, so I can't accept it as the answer. Can you try making it work for the DataStorePool's AcquireChangeProvider method?